# Wordpress Contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

I have made a thank you page on my word press site and redirected the contact form 7 to show that page once user submits the information.

Is there a way to show the information the user entered in the form on the thank you page? If so can someone help me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below line on Additional Settings field at the bottom of the contact form management page

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://domain.com/thankyoupage';"
```

you can pass info as querystring

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how a query string can be built with information added from contact form 7 in this URL
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://domain.com/thankyoupage';"

I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks,

Comment: you can call like below function:

add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'custom_wpcf7_mail_sent');
function custom_wpcf7_mail_sent($wpcf7)
{
 $on_sent_ok = $wpcf7->additional_setting('ip_on_sent_ok', false);

 if (is_array($on_sent_ok) && count($on_sent_ok) > 0)
 {
  wp_redirect(trim($on_sent_ok[0]) . '?email=' . $wpcf7->posted_data['user-email']);
  exit;
 }
}